# SQL - Looking to return rolling date values

Tags: mysql, sql

Using Navicat for mySQL

I have two tables, one with a service date field (tbl_service) and one with a claim date field (tbl_claims). Trying to return only records where the service date is within 365 days of the claim date. Below is my best guess, but it's returning some records that don't fall in the date range:

```
select
tbl_service.vin,
tbl_service.service_date,
tbl_claims.claim_Date
from
tbl_claims inner join tbl_service on tbl_claims.vin = tbl_service.vin
where
tbl_service.service_date < tbl_claims.claim_date + 365 and
tbl_service.service_date > tbl_claims.claim_date
```

This almost works but I'm still getting claim dates that are more than 365 days past service date. I got this "+ 365" formatting from when I used Access, wondering if that is the issue? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If this is Access - please tag it with that - as it has it's own unique flavour. Most dialects allow for between too - not sure about Access...  `tbl_server.service_date between tbl_claims.claim_date and DateAdd("d", 365 ,tbl_claims.claim_date)` - according to this seems this might work https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/add-to-or-subtract-from-date-and-time-values-9b4d1adc-d54f-4dbb-a759-79b17dcd0df1 https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/between-and-operator-a435878d-63f7-4825-8c31-999432ae8223

Comment: Please tag the proper `DBMS` you are using (Oracle, SQL Server, Access) etc, regardless if Access is the front end or not

Answer (score 0):

If these are dates, then use the interval syntax or `date_add()`:

```
where tbl_service.service_date < tbl_claims.claim_date + interval 365 day and
      tbl_service.service_date > tbl_claims.claim_date
```

MySQL has a tendency to convert dates to numbers when faced with arithmetic calculations.  I'll let you figure out what 20200301 + 365 comes out to.